# How to Vertical align elements of a list?

Tags: html, css

I have a `ul` where one of its children is positioned on the left side (vertically centered with absolute position), but the rest of the items have to be vertically aligned as well but displayed as a column.

The left li is all right, I just can't find a way to vertically align a list of elements

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7frcd5mx/) where I show how this works currently

```css
#outer {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.notAligned {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    top: 50%;
    top: calc(50% - 25px);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 35%; } 

.inner {
  margin-left: 50% !important;
  width: 50%;
  position: static;
}




/* Structure */
#outer {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f443363b;
}

.inner {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 3em;
  margin: 5px 0;}
```

```html
<ul id="outer">
  <li class="notAligned">Not Aligned</li>
  <li class="inner">Aligned</li>
  <li class="inner">Aligned</li>
  <li class="inner">Aligned</li>
  <li class="inner">Aligned</li>
  <li class="inner">Aligned</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you please explain more. do you want to align everything to a specific side or?? do you want to horizontally align? is that what you mean? the list is always aligning everything as a column by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible with the use of `flexbox`

http://jsfiddle.net/zvaqhs40/

```css
#outer {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.notAligned {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 35%;
}

.inner {
  margin-left: 50% !important;
  width: 50%;
  position: static;
}

/* Structure */
#outer {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f443363b;
}

.inner {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 3em;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

ol, ul, li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="outer">
  <li class="notAligned">Not Aligned</li>
  <li class="inner">Aligned</li>
  <li class="inner">Aligned</li>
  <li class="inner">Aligned</li>
  <li class="inner">Aligned</li>
  <li class="inner">Aligned</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you want text should be in center you should use `text-align:center` in the ul class

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the use of `css-grid`. you can avoid the use of `position: absolute` and `margin`. i have removed unwanted `css` to keep it minimal.

```css
#outer {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f443363b;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5,1fr);
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.notAligned {
  grid-row: span 5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  grid-column: span 2;} 

/* Structure */
.inner {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 3em;
  margin: 5px 0;
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```

```html
<ul id="outer">
  <li class="notAligned">Not Aligned</li>
  <li class="inner">Aligned</li>
  <li class="inner">Aligned</li>
  <li class="inner">Aligned</li>
  <li class="inner">Aligned</li>
  <li class="inner">Aligned</li>
</ul>
```